# ABC test/ hypothesis testing with multiple comparisons

Tags: hypothesis-testing, bonferroni, ab-test

I need to do a hypothesis test with three versions (one control version and two test versions).  From what I understand I can just run a t-test (or z-test) for each test version vs control, and then use some kind of correction (such a bonferroni correction) and see if one is significant (and if they both are see which one has the highest lift).

Assuming this is right, how do I run a sample size calculation for this?  Can I just run the sample size calculation for both versions of the test (control vs test a and control vs test b) and then aggregate that way.  I guess I would take the bonferroni correction into account when determining significance level for the sample size calculation.  Does this seem right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it is best to do an ANOVA to see if there are *any* significant
differences among the three levels of the factor. If so, then
do *ad hoc* tests along with some method (such as Bonferroni) to
avoid 'false discovery'.

Unless I had some previous experience with similar data to feel
confident that the three levels all have the same variability, I'd use
`oneway.test` in R, which does not assume equal variances.

Example:

```
ctrl = rnorm(20, 50, 2)
trta = rnorm(20, 51, 2)
trtb = rnorm(20, 52, 2.2)
x = c(ctrl, trta, trtb)
g = rep(1:3, each=20)
boxplot(x~g, col="skyblue2")
```

[image]

```
oneway.test(x~g)

    One-way analysis of means 
    (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and g
F = 4.1362, num df = 2.000, denom df = 37.975, p-value = 0.02371
```

So there are significant differences at the 5% level. It seems obvious that the control and treatment B must differ. Then we could do *ad hoc*
Welch t tests at the 2% level to see if we can distinguish between treatments A and B, and between control and treatment A.
In my fictitious example, we cannot say treatment a is significantly
different from the other two levels of the factor.

```
t.test(ctrl, trta)$p.val
[1] 0.06865211           # not signif
t.test(trta, trtb)$p.val
[1] 0.3030164            # not signif
t.test(ctrl, trtb)$p.val
[1] 0.007009848          # signif as surmised
```

There are procedures in R, other statistical software, and online
to suggest sample sizes for the three levels, given the size of
difference $\Delta$ we want to detect, the (common) SD $\sigma$ of the three groups, and the desired power. Most of these require equal
variability in the levels and equal sample sizes. However, it is
possible to relatively simple simulations in R to check whether
particular sample sizes give adequate power for given $\Delta$ and $\sigma_i.$

In the fictitious situation above we might use $\sigma_1 = \sigma_2 = 2, \sigma_3 = 2.2,$ and $\Delta = 1.$ We found that $n = 20$ was large enough for
the main ANOVA, but not large enough for the *ad hoc* tests (where smaller values of $\Delta$ may be required). So, as you suggest, we should focus on the power of the t tests.

By trial and error, it is easy to see that $n=80$ suffices to get power about 74% for a
Welch t test with $\Delta=1, \sigma_1=2, \sigma_2-2.2,$ and significance level $\alpha = 2\%.$ (And $n-100$ for power about 84%.)

```
pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(80,50,2),rnorm(80,51,2.2))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .02)
[1]  0.74339

pv = replicate(10^5, t.test(rnorm(100,50,2),rnorm(100,51,2.2))$p.val)
mean(pv <= .02)
[1] 0.84551
```

The search can be hurried along by (a) using $10^4$ replications early on and (b) using standard formulas involving noncentral t distributions for pooled t tests which have slightly better power than do Welch t tests.